# Controlling the flow of requests without dropping them - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I have a simple nodejs webserver running, it:

1. Accepts requests
2. Spawns separate thread to perform background processing
3. Background thread returns results
4. App responds to client

Using Apache benchmark "ab -r -n 100 -c 10", performing 100 requests with 10 at a time.

Average response time of 5.6 seconds.

My logic for using nodejs is that is typically quite resource efficient, especially when the bulk of the work is being done by another process. Seems like the most lightweight webserver option for this scenario.

**The Problem**

With 10 concurrent requests my CPU was maxed out, which is no surprise since there is CPU intensive work going on the background.

Scaling horizontally is an easy thing to, although I want to make the most out of each server for obvious reasons.

So how with nodejs, either raw or some framework, how can one keep that under control as to not go overkill on the CPU.

**Potential Approach?**

Could accepting the request storing it in a db or some persistent storage and having a separate process that uses an async library to process x at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your potential approach, you're basically describing a queue. You can store incoming messages (jobs) there and have each process get one job at the time, only getting the next one when processing the previous job has finished. You could spawn a number of processes working in parallel, like an amount equal to the number of cores in your system. Spawning more won't help performance, because multiple processes sharing a core will just run slower. Keeping one core free might be preferred to keep the system responsive for administrative tasks.

Many different queues exist. A node-based one using redis for persistence that seems to be well supported is [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue) (I have no personal experience using it). I found a tutorial for building an implementation with Kue [here](https://medium.com/node-js-tips-tricks/implementing-a-job-queue-with-node-js-ffcfbc824b01). Depending on the software your environment is running in though, another choice might make more sense.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Message queue sounds like the best way here, thanks!